# Plugin should be merged into plugins

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

[plugin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/plugin) should be merged into [plugins](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/plugins), there shouldn't be a need for two of them.

Comment: Just did this. Yay!

Answer (score 7):

## Yes.

[plugin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/plugin) should be merged into [plugins](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/plugins).

Comment: Singular and plural versions of the same word are usually a pretty straightforward synonym-and-merge case. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear Sssh, I'm still new at this thing. :)

Answer (score -1):

## No.

They are two separate tags, they mean different things and shouldn't be merged.